# How do I pair up multiple keys with one values from a dictionary through a function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

**I have the following problem and I cannot figure out what to do. Can someone help???**

"You are throwing a party and want to pair up people with similar interests.
You have already collected data about each of your guest’s favorite interest in
a dictionary like so:

> interests = { 'Sophia' : 'Computer', 'Anders' : 'Dancing', 'Mette' :
> 'Dancing', 'Hikari' : 'Computer', 'Riko' : 'Rowing', 'Troels' :
> 'Rowing', 'Sarah' : 'Rowing' }

To be able to quickly suggest topics at the party, you need to convert this
dictionary into a different layout.

Your task is to write a function transform_dictionary that takes as argument
a dictionary such as the one above and returns a dictionary in which
each key is an interest and the value is a list of all the people that share this
interest.
For example, for the list above, the dictionary that is returned is
(disregarding a particular order of elements)

I need to print:

> {'Computer': ['Sophia', 'Hikari'], 'Dancing': ['Anders', 'Mette'], 'Rowing': ['Riko', 'Troels', 'Sarah']}

**This is what I have so far:**

```
    interests = {
        'Sophia' : 'Computer',
        'Anders' : 'Dancing',
        'Mette' : 'Dancing', 
        'Hikari' : 'Computer',
        'Riko' : 'Rowing', 
        'Troels' : 'Rowing',
        'Sarah' : 'Rowing'
    }
    
    # comvert dictionary into a different layout.
    
    def transform_dictionary(interests):
        new_dict = {}
        key_list = []
        
        for k, v in new_dict:
            if value in new_dict:
            new_dict[value] = k
        return {}
        
    
    print(transform_dictionary(interests))
```

Comment: You iterate over empty `new_dict`, which will do nothing

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) then only  use `append` like below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in interests.items():
    dct[v].append(k)
```

Output:

```
{'Computer': ['Sophia', 'Hikari'],
 'Dancing': ['Anders', 'Mette'],
 'Rowing': ['Riko', 'Troels', 'Sarah']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
interests = {
    'Sophia' : 'Computer',
    'Anders' : 'Dancing',
    'Mette' : 'Dancing', 
    'Hikari' : 'Computer',
    'Riko' : 'Rowing', 
    'Troels' : 'Rowing',
    'Sarah' : 'Rowing'
}

# convert dictionary into a different layout.

def transform_dictionary(interests):
    new_dict = {}
    for v in interests.values():
        new_dict[v] = [i for i in interests if interests[i] == v]
    return new_dict
    

print(transform_dictionary(interests))
```

Output:

```
{'Computer': ['Sophia', 'Hikari'], 'Dancing': ['Anders', 'Mette'], 'Rowing': ['Riko', 'Troels', 'Sarah']}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
def transform_dictionary(interests):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in interests.items():
        if not value in new_dict:
            new_dict[value] = [key]
        else:
            new_dict[value] += [key]
    return new_dict
```